# How to design a colour class that has already pre-defined standard colours in the most elegant c++ way?

Tags: c++, class, design-patterns

How to design a Colour class that has already pre-defined the standard colours in the modern elegant c++ way?
I would like to know a minimal example design that does so instead of a complete colour class.

I have the basic Colour class:

```
class Colour
{
    public:
    double rgb[3];
};
```

Now I can use it in the following way:

```
Colour c1 = {1.0, 0.0, 0.0}, c2 = {1.0, 1.0, 0.0};
```

But since there are already standard colours very common to us that we will always like to use
something like the following:

```
Colour c1 = Colour::Red, c2 = Colour::Yellow;
```

How to achieve the above?

Advance thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to provide a converting constructor in `Colour` class then you can define standard colours to be arrays and then convert to Colour object at the time of construction.

```cpp
#include <array>

struct Colour {
    Colour(std::array<double, 3> _rgb) : rgb(_rgb) {}

    std::array<double, 3> rgb;

    static constexpr auto Red = std::array<double, 3>{1.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    static constexpr auto Yellow = std::array<double, 3>{1.0, 1.0, 0.0};
};

Colour c1 = Colour::Red, c2 = Colour::Yellow;
```

Comment: I would write `static constexpr std::array<double, 3> Red{1.0,0.0,0.0}, Yellow{1.0,1.0,0.0}, ...;` for convenience. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

With a slightly different syntax, you can use static member functions:

```cpp
struct Colour {
    double rgb[3];

    static constexpr Colour Red() {
        return {1, 0, 0};
    }
};

auto red = Colour::Red();
```

Alternatively, you can put standard colours into a special namespace:

```cpp
namespace Colours {
    inline constexpr auto Red = Colour{1, 0, 0};
}

auto red = Colours::Red;
```

Comment: What if I choose to use static member variables instead of static member functions? I can say that at least I will not have to type so much, for say, number of standard colours being 30 or above. Going the function way seems to be too much unneccesary coding? What are advantages and disadvantages of using functions &/or variables in such cases?

Comment: @user62039, unfortunately, you can't use a static data member of type `T` inside `T` itself. Otherwise, a static data member would probably be a better choice.